# Excel, if column is greater than zero and another column contains "Competitor", subtract the value of another column by one

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to working on something that seems sort of complicated in Excel but it's probably not that hard.

[image]

Looking a the picture above, I want a formula to run in column W that will do the following:
IF U2 (just using the cell but will need to be true for the entire column) > 0 AND D2 = "Competitor" Then Column W1 = U2 - 1.

Here is what I wrote so far (minus the if U2 > 0)

```
=if (D2 = "Competitor",W2 = U2-1,U2)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use AND():

```
=IF(AND(D2="Competitor",U2>0),U2-1,U2)
```

Comment: Awesome. That did it.